# error: [eof $FILE_NAME]

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to write a script in TCL,

I get an error in the line: `![eof $logfile_fd]`

The error is: `invalid command name "!0"`

What may cause this, and how can I fix it?

```
if {[file exists $logfile] != 1} {
    puts "Error existence of $logfile"
    return -1
}

if {[catch {set logfile_fd [open "$logfile" r]} err]} {
    puts "Error opening \"$logfile\" $err"
    return -1
}   
seek $logfile_fd 0

![eof $logfile_fd]
```

I tried to use another solution:

```
while {[gets $logfile_fd line] >= 0} {
   ...do something with $line... 
}
```

But I got an other error:

```
list element in quotes followed by ")\nindexRecordsRead:" instead of space
```

whilst

> )\nindexRecordsRead:

is some text inside `$logfile_fd` ... I think TCL tries to executes it or something... It works fine for each other line till this line...

Thanks!

Comment: We cannot solve your current problem without seeing the code inside the `while`; none of what you have currently showed us can throw that error (which definitely comes from the list parser, which is used by many Tcl commands). Copy-and-paste it in please. Also, it would be helpful to have the error trace from the `errorInfo` global variable. (Are you inside eggdrop? That's the only Tcl software I know that doesn't tell you error traces by default…)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to put this, before working with `$line`

```
set bugfree_line [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $line]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do.  eof is testing for an end of file condition - using it "bare" like that doesn't do anything.  Tcl is evaluating the [eof $logfile_fd] to 0, and then trying to execute the command !0, which doesn't exist.

It does work if you have something like:

```
if {![eof $logfile_fd]} {
  //do something
}
```

or, if you want to store the results for later, you can do:

```
set isEndOfFile [expr {![eof $logfile_fd]}]
```

But, executing like you are, I'm not aware of any side effects you might be wanting to get without using the return value (other than throwing an error if the file descriptor is invalid).

Comment: I guess, if you are using Tcl interactively, you might want to know if you are at the end of the file (although then, you could easily interpret the results of just eof $logfile_fd yourself).  But, if that is the case, you want to change that to expr {![eof $logfile_fd]} to display the result you want.  The explanation is that ! doesn't have a meaning outside of an expr, so what you currently have just does a string concatenation of ! and the result of the eof - you need to evaluate it to get the negation behaviour you are expecting.

Comment: Hey, first of all, thanks...

I just wanted to make it more simple, so I just wrote the `![eof $logfile_fd]`, But actually I use it as a `while` condition, Inside the `while` I read all the lines, till the file is over (eof)...

I think it is something that relate to something with `lists` & the `$logfile` itself..

I tried to use another method for reading lines:
`set file_data [read $fp] ;  set data [split $file_data "\n"]
     foreach line $data {
          # do some line processing here
     }`

and I got another error concern some lists thing...

Comment: @hudac: If you're reading lines from a file in a loop, use `while {[gets $fp line] >= 0} { ...do something with $line... }` (since the two-argument form of `gets` returns the line length, or -1 at EOF).

Comment: I get another error: `list element in quotes followed by ")\nindexRecordsRead:" instead of space`, while `)\nindexRecordsRead:` is some text inside `$logfile_fd` ...

I think TCL tries to executes it or something...

It works till this line...

Comment: I don't know if it relates, but in he same line, couple of words before, I have this : `d\nkey` , and TCL doesn't say anything about this thing... (because of the `\n`)

Comment: Maybe posting a little more of the file or what you are actually doing  with the lines would help troubleshoot.  One shot in the dark that I have - are there literal \n sequences in the file that you are trying to match with "\n"?  Tcl will translate the "\n" as a newline and not the literal \n, so your input may not be what you think it is.

Comment: Another shot in the dark - are you using Donal's suggestion to use the while {gets...} convention?  And then doing something like foreach l $line {.. do something}?  That would cause problems, because the gets will just return one line at a time.  That will be a string, not a list, so foreach can choke because it is expecting a well formatted list.  Said another way, taking your comment and Donal's suggestion, the [gets $fp line] effectively replaces your split AND foreach commands - you just have to do the #do some line processing# part inside the while loop.

Comment: @ramanman thanks for the comment, I tried to use 2 solutions, **1.** `while {[gets $fp line] >= 0} { ...do something with $line... }`, **2.** `set file_data [read $fp] ; set data [split $file_data "\n"]`
My purpose is to take a text that inside some file, and do something with it, does it matter what there is in this file? for other files, this solution works great... I didn't do what you describe with the `foreach`

Comment: This is getting off topic from the original question - maybe a new post is in order.  In any case, it does matter what you are trying to do.  line will be a string.  That error indicates you are trying to do a list operation on it (foreach, lsearch, llength, etc).  Sometimes you get lucky and Tcl does the right thing, sometimes the exact text in the file causes the interpretation of line as a list to fail.